# Finding nonsimilar solutions to the matrix equation $ Y^2 = Y $.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $Y \in M_n $. We have $ Y^2 = Y \Longleftrightarrow Y(Y-I) = 0 $. This means that the vectors in $ Y-I $ are in the nullspace of $ Y$. This means that $ Y $ is a projection (also because the characteristic polynomial is $x^2-x=0$, which has the only roots 0 and 1). Non-similar solutions are then given by non-similar projection matrices, which should be those with unequal ranks. There are thus $n$ non-similar solutions (from rank 1 to rank $n$ projections, where a rank $n$ projection would be defined to just be a positive-definite unitary matrix; if one counts the zero matrix, then that would be $n+1$ solutions, I guess). Since projections are diagonalizable, it is pretty trivial that projections of equal rank are similar to each other. Is there more to this problem than meets the eye?
Edit: the rank-$n$ projection should just be the identity matrix, I believe.

Comment: This is all true. Shortly you can say that the solutions to this equation are given by $\begin{pmatrix} E_m & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ with $0 \leq m \leq n$

Comment: My only criticism would be considering rank $0$ as an exception, but not rank $n$. Both are perfectly valid values for the rank, both happen to have unique solutions among projections. In fact $P\mapsto I-P$ is an involutive symmetry on the set of projections$~P$, which interchanges their eigenspaces for $0$ and $1$, and which maps rank $r$ to rank $n-r$.

Comment: Oops, forget one more thing: $x^2-x$ is **not** the characteristic polynomial (which is of degree$~n$ rather than$~2$). It *is* an annihilating polynomial though, and this suffices to limit the possible eigenvalues to its roots $0,1$, as well as ensures (because its roots are simple) that $Y$ will be diagonalisable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. The only thing I want to note is that you can prove your observation without even using the notion of eigenvalues, eigenvectors and diagonalization.

If $T \colon V \rightarrow V$ satisfies $T^2 = T$ then given $v \in V$ you can write $v = Tv + (v - Tv)$ which shows that $V = \ker(T) + \mathrm{im}(T)$. If $v = Tu \in \ker(T) \cap \mathrm{im}(T)$ then $0 = Tv = T^2u = Tu = v$ showing that $V = \ker(T) \oplus \mathrm{im}(T)$. By choosing a basis for $\ker(T)$ and $\mathrm{im}(T)$ you see that the matrix representing $T$ is $\mathrm{diag}(0_{n - m}, I_m)$ where $0 \leq m = \dim \mathrm{im}(T) \leq \dim V = n$. This shows that every projection matrix is similar to $\mathrm{diag}(0_{n-m}, I_m)$ and if a matrix $A$ is similar to $\mathrm{diag}(0_{n-m}, I_m)$ then it clearly satisfies $A^2 = A$. Finally, the matrices $\{\mathrm{diag}(0_{n-m}, I_m)\}_{m=0}^{n}$ are not similar to each other because similar matrices have the same rank.